# What is the correct syntax and command in this shell_exec() case?

Tags: php, ffmpeg, shell-exec

Please help me to find the right syntax and command in this line to fetch some metadata for the specified row and column:

```
shell_exec('ffmpeg -i ' . $targetPath . -metadata album={echo $row_release['release_title'];} ' -b:a 320k '. $mp3);
```

I am confused, especially with this part

```
-metadata album={echo $row_release['release_title'];} ' -b:a
```

Are *echo* and *brackets* OK, because it does not execute it.

Thanks guys and girls!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the 'echo' and try this:

```
shell_exec('ffmpeg -i ' . $targetPath . ' -metadata album="' . $row_release['release_title'] . '" -b:a 320k ' . $mp3);
```

Another problem may be that some versions of `ffmpeg` do not support MP3 as an encoder/output format. In that case you'd have to use another format. Specify this new format with the `-acodec` option. The list of valid formats can be retrieved with `ffmpeg -codecs`. All entries with an `E` are valid encoders.

So, for example, you can use MPEG1/Layer2(MP2):

```
shell_exec('ffmpeg -i ' . $targetPath . ' -metadata album="' . $row_release['release_title'] . '" -acodec mp2 -b:a 320k ' . $mp3);
```

This sets the 'album' metadata as well as converts the file to MP2.

The same applies to MP3, of course, if supported.

Comment: *ffmpeg does not support MP3 as an encoder/output format.* --> of course, it does.

Comment: Thank you @zx485 it is encoding mp3, but not including my row. Maybe I am failing to declare the variables?

`code`
$query_release = "select * from tbl_release_info where release_id = $rid;";
$query_sr = "select * from tbl_sound_recordings where release_id = $rid;";
$result_sr = mysql_query ($query_sr);

$result_release = mysql_query ($query_release);

$row_release = mysql_fetch_assoc ($result_release);

Comment: @Mulvya: I changed my answer to reflect that. I was surprised, too, that my version obviously did not. So I relativized my argument. The way to find out _if or if not_ was present from the beginning.

Comment: @mgeezy: That seems probable. I tested my answer with simple variables and it worked as desired. I suggest `var_dump()`ing the vars before the `shell_exec` to check if everything if correct. I used `$row_release = array(xyz=>"cde", release_title=>"Such a nice title");` for testing.